# convergence of a tower power

Tags: calculus

Prove that the sequence of general term $(\frac 12)^{(\frac 13)^{(\frac 14)^{...\frac 1n}}}$ is convergent.
the three dots are antidiagonal of course :)
My try was to compare it with some easier one like the power tower of $\frac 12$.
I conjectured with wolframalpha that it can be divided to two subsequences which seem to be adjacent but i'm finding it hard to prove it
Can anyone give some hints.

Comment: A quick check with Mathematica shows that odd terms tend to 0.690347 while even terms tend to 0.658366.

Comment: do you mean the sequence can be nonconvergent ?

Comment: So it seems: I've gone as far as n=1000 and the two subsequences converge quite fast, but to different limits.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the result of computing your sequence with Mathematica. It is apparent that odd and even subsequences separately converge to two different limits.

```
f[n_] := Fold[Power[#2, #1] &, 1, Table[1/k, {k, n, 2, -1}]]

N[f[500], 20]
0.65836559926633118818

N[f[1000], 20]
0.65836559926633118818

N[f[499], 20]
0.69034712611496431947

N[f[999], 20]
0.69034712611496431947

DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: very clear thanks a lot (y)

Comment: Can anyone help or provide a way of proving it.