# What's equal this:${\frac 12 ^ \frac 13} ^{\cdots \frac1n}$?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, perfect-powers

I want to know wht's equal this number :${\frac 12 ^ \frac 13} ^{\cdots \frac1n}$, however it's seems trivial that is converge to 1 , but i don't know how i can evaluate it , Really i have two question: the first is : what is the partial sum of it ? and what's equal for n large enough or go to infty ?

Comment: Clarify the order of the brackets. In particular, is the third term $\left(\frac 12\right)^{\left(\frac 13^{\frac 14}\right)}$ or $\left(\frac 12 ^ \frac 13\right) ^ \frac 14$ (which can be simplified, of course)?

Comment: (1/2)^(1/3)^(1/4)................^(1/n)

Comment: I think the convention is that you always do the "higher" exponents first, because (a^b)^c can be written more easily as a^(bc), so that's why a^b^c usually means a^(b^c).

Comment: I tried playing with some of these terms in Mathematica and to me it doesn't look like it converges to 1.  I tried n = 30 and if I did the computation right, the output was .658285.  Here is the code I used:
n = 30;
f[x_] := (n = n - 1; (1/n)^x)
NestList[f, 1./n, n - 2]

Comment: what "partial sum" is there??

Comment: @DanielV The sequence $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$ is monotonically increasing in the range $(0,1)$ and has limit $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How do you know it's monotonically increasing?

Comment: Also look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1458506/279515 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683961/279515

Comment: @mathworker21 It is definitely not an increasing sequence. It goes up, down, up, down,... The first terms are $\{0.5, 0.79\ldots,0.59\ldots,0.73\ldots,\ldots\}$. This is easy enough to prove, but the demonstration here in the comments is quicker with the decimals. Whatever the limit is, it is between $0.59\ldots$ and $0.73\ldots$.

Comment: @alex.jordan [There seem to be two accumulation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1458679/6460) of around $0.6583656$ and $0.6903471$